# SEO plugin doesn't work in Hippo CMS

Tags: seo, freemarker, hippocms

I'm using Hippo CMS and trying to implement SEO plugin. I did everything by manual but I don't see any changes and meta tags in rendered results.

My basic layout is:

```html
<#include "/WEB-INF/freemarker/include/imports.ftl">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <@hst.headContributions/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<@hst.link  path="/css/bootstrap.css"/>" type="text/css"/>
    <@hst.defineObjects/>
    <#if hstRequest.requestContext.cmsRequest>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="<@hst.link  path="/css/cms-request.css"/>" type="text/css"/>
    </#if>
</head>
```

And I just enable plugin over Hippo Setup -> features. And sure then rebuild and run all again.
Then I'm going to Channel Editor -> Edit Page -> Add Component. The drag n drop component on page.

I did all changes by clicking on component. But anyway I don't see any changes on published page.

I didn't find any documentation about that, but maybe somebody resolve this issue and can help to me!

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any exceptions or does it 'just not' work?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it out as well. It indeed does not work out of the box as you would expect. The component uses a template specific of the Setup feature, the seo.ftl. This makes it work as a draggable component in the channel manager. What it does not do is add the configured data to the html head.

If you check the seohelper.ftl [1] of the forge plugin, there you see the code that does this job. What you can do to make it work in your project is add the headcontribution tags as in [1] to seo.ftl. Also make sure you have a <@hst.headcontributions/> tag in the html head section of the base-layout.ftl of your project.

I will create a jira issue for this so.

[1] http://forge.onehippo.org/gf/project/hst-seo-support/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=%2F*checkout*%2Fhst-seo-support%2Fbranches%2Fhst-seo-support-1.01.xx%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Forg%2Fonehippo%2Fforge%2Fseo%2Fsupport%2Fseohelper.ftl&revision=157

Comment: This is the issue that you may track for progress: https://issues.onehippo.com/browse/ESSENTIALS-572